# How to refresh a DIV's content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which is filled with XML content using javascript. At the moment, I would like this the "displayCode" div content to refresh using a button. codeContainer is displayCode's container. Currently, the code refreshes the whole html page into the div, instead of just the content you would get if you refreshed the page. I have tried every other method online, and all of them either return a blank div or the entire page copied into the div. 
And yes, I have named the jQuery in the header.

tl;dr:
Why is my .load not working?

**Current code:**

```html
<body>
<script>
function buttontest() {
        alert('pressed')
       $('#displayCode').load('index.html #displayCode');
};

</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="buttontest()">Click me</button>
<div id = "codeContainer">
<div id='displayCode'></div><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first of all there should be a `type="button"` on the button becuase the default `type` is `submit`

```
//I Applied the click Listener on the id rather than having a function
<button id="loadContent" type="button">Click me</button>
```

, and you want to make sure you have `.min.js` version of jquery not `.slim.min.js` version because that does not have AJAX (hopefully that makes sense).This may not be necessary but i don't think you need `target` to `load` the content.so

```
$("#displayCode").load("./index.html"); // Adjust the file path accordingly
```

should do.Apart from that you should be good.

I Made a working example, you can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fire-wyqq1)

Comment: Thank you! Using your example, I figured out that I needed to use a separate .html document to retrieve the data, and then fetch the refresh data from there over the main form (I hope that makes sense!).